# PowerPoint 2013 shows preview of recent presentations. How to disable this behaviour?

Tags: powerpoint, office-2013, powerpoint-2013

I am using a COM-Addin in PowerPoint 2013.This add-in does some processing and shows a message (say "Document is going to open") to the user, when the user tries to open any existing presentation.

This addin is working fine with previous versions of PowerPoint. But as PowerPoint 2013 shows the preview of recently opened presentations to the user and in order to do so, it needs to open the file. The add-in starts processing and the message box is shown, even when we are on the welcome page of PPT 2013 and no document is opened by the user.

I don't want to disable the "Recent Presentation" option. Therefore I was wondering if there is a way to prevent PowerPoint from generating the preview of recent document by changing some setting in registry etc. Or if there is any API which can be used to prevent this behavior of PowerPoint.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the reason for showing the user the message?  If they've just told PPT to open a document, they're already expecting the document to open, no?  Is it along the lines of a progress dialog ... iow, your processing slows down the document opening time, so you're letting them know "Be patient. Soon."?  It might be possible to trap the document open event but before doing anything else, test to see if the document is open in a window.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I was trying to capture PresentationOpen event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211560(v=office.11).aspx). But was unable to capture this event. I think the event is not generated when the presentation preview is shown. As this event was generated and captured when the presentation is opened explicitly.

Comment: So it turns out that there's no problem, then?